# htaccess 301 redirect with a dynamic page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic, redirect, http-status-code-301

In htaccess, how do you 301 redirect dynamic pages?

For example, what if I wanted a rule that made `/get.php?i=1234` to redirect to `/i/1234`, etcetera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite like redirection as in this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(i)=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^get\.php$ %1/%2? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [RedirectMatch directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). It depends on [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) so that's probably always enabled. You can use mod_rewrite for that too but it might be overkill. The replacement may contain references in the form of $n:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/get\.php\?i=([0-9]+)$ /i/$1
```

As you can imagine, `$1` is a *reference* to what's **matched inside the pair of parenthesis #1**. You can have many references:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/get\.php\?i=([0-9]+)&y=([0-9]+)$ /i/$1/$2/
```

You can use an online [regular expression tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) to elaborate your apache config: if i put `^/get\.php\?i=([0-9]+)&y=([0-9]+)$` in the "Regexp" input, and `/get.php?i=12&y=24` in the "Subject string" input, then click "Show match" it shows:

```
Match at position 0:
/get.php?i=12&y=24
12  # first reference available
24  # second reference available
```

If your regexps don't work in the tester, they not likely to work in an apache configuration. You should try them in the tester first.